# Image reconstruction using SVD Decomposition

Tags: c++, c, svd

I have performed block SVD decomposition over image and I stored results.
Now, I need to make reconstruction from this results. I found few examples all written in Matlab, which is a mystery for me.
I only need formula from which I can reconstruct my picture, or example written in C language.
Matrix A is equal U*S*V'. How will look formula, e.g. for calculating first five singular values (product of which rows and columns)? Please provide formula with indexes in C like style. U and V' are matrices and S is vector (not matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get your question right, but if you just need to know singular values, they are the diagonal values of the middle matrix S. S in general is a diagonal matrix, which is stored here as a vector. I mean, only the diagonal is stored, you should imagine it as a matrix if you're thinking in matrix calculations.

Those diagonal values are your singular values, if you need the first biggest singular values, just take the 5 biggest values of the vector S.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition):

> The diagonal entries Σi,i of Σ are known as the singular values of M. 
>   The m columns of U and the n columns of V are called the left-singular 
>   vectors and right-singular vectors of M, respectively.

In the above quote, sigma is your S, and M is the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for C code, yet my hope is that pseudocode will suffice (it's late, I'm tired). The target matrix **A** has *m* rows, *c* columns and rank rho. The variable *p* = *min(m,n)*.

One strategy is to first form the the intermediate matrix product **B** = **U****S**. This is trivial due to the diagonal-like nature of the matrix of singular values. Assume you have rho ( = 5 ) singular values. You must enforce rho <= *p*.

Replace column vector *u*<sub>1</sub> with *s*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>.

Replace column vector *u*<sub>2</sub> with *s*<sub>2</sub>*u*<sub>2</sub>.
   ...

Replace column vector *u*<sub>rho</sub> with *s*<sub>rho</sub>*u*<sub>rho</sub>.

Replace column vector *u*<sub>rho+1</sub> with a zero vector of length *m*.

Replace column vector *u*<sub>rho+2</sub> with a zero vector of length *m*.

...

Replace column vector *u*<sub>p</sub> with a zero vector of length *m*.

Next form the new image matrix **A** = **B****V**<sup>T</sup>. The matrix element in row *r* and column *c* is the dot product of the *r*th row vector (length rho) of **B** with the *c*th column vector (length rho) of **V**<sup>T</sup>.

Another strategy is to jump to the form where the matrix elements of **A** in row *r* and column *c* are

*a*<sub>r,c</sub> = sum ( *s*<sub>k</sub>*u*<sub>r,k</sub>*v*<sub>c,k</sub>, { k, 1, rho } )

The row counter *r* runs from 1 to *m*; the column counter *c* runs from 1 to *n*.